# I rewrote my code using fetch, and its not working

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I rewrote my code using `fetch` instead of using callbacks, now the page is letting me loop through the API data.  Even though I can see the data being fetched from the API in the console, when I use console.log.

Now I am getting this error message

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at scripting.js:30:40
```

```
runCode.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    
    fetch(theUrl)
        .then(response=>{response.json()})
        .then((data)=>{
            for(let i=0;i<data.length; i++){
                generateHTML(data[i]);
            }
        })
    });
```

Comment: `response.json()` returns another promise.

Comment: I am now getting this error message , I changed to the code to the code above
"Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at scripting.js:30:40"

Answer (score 1):

[`response.json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json) returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), which you need to wait for.

You can do this by chaining [`Promise#then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then).

```js
fetch(theUrl).then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
    // now use data
});
```

You could also use `await` in an `async` function.

```js
runCode.addEventListener("click", async e => {
    let data = await (await fetch(theUrl)).json();
    // use data here
});
```

Comment: I changed the code but now I am getting this error message for the for loop
"Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at scripting.js:30:40"

Comment: I get "undefined"

Comment: @myko You made a typo in copying over the code in my answer. It must be `.then(response => response.json())` **without** extra curly braces (i.e. remove the `{}`).

Comment: aha that worked after I fixed that, thank you so much